# OpenGL context in mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, opengl

How could I do the same thing this objective-c code does for iphone but for mac?

```
EAGLContext *k_context = [[[EAGLContext alloc]
                           initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1
                           sharegroup:[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] context] sharegroup]] autorelease];    
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:k_context];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple explains it really well in their [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH207-TP9). On MacOS X there are three ways to create OpenGL contexts:

- [Fullscreen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH210-SW6)
- [Windowed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_drawing/opengl_drawing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH404-SW8)
- [Off-Screen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH403-SW2)